# Prompt for rephrasing a question based on previous questions

Tags: prompt-design, gpt-3.5-turbo

I am trying to write a prompt on GPT 3.5 turbo to rephrase a question based on context of previous questions. I did write a prompt that is able to suffice 90% of the cases however at times LLM even rephrases questions that are standalone and need not be rephrased. Basically LLM is not able to figure out whether a question is standalone and needs no rephrasing or it has to be rephrased.

For e.g.
Input prompt: What is generative AI?
Rephrased prompt from LLM: Can you explain generative AI?
Input prompt : How is it impacting the world?
Rephrased prompt from LLM: How is generative AI impacting the world?
Input prompt: What is digital?
Expected rephrased prompt from LLM: Can you explain what is digital?
Actual rephrased prompt from LLM: Can you explain digital in context of generative AI?

Need help to fine tune the prompt.

Existing prompt:
Given an ongoing conversation and a follow up question, your task is to rephrase the follow-up question. While rephrasing take into account the context of ongoing conversation to form a standalone question that delivers more information than the follow up question. If the follow up question is not related to the ongoing conversation, simply rephrase the question

Using Azure Open AI API's for using GPT 3.5 turbo model.

Usage: Using Langchain conversational chain to call Azure Open AI GPT 3.5 model maintaining a history of last three prompts.

`bufferMemory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=3)`
`conversation = ConversationChain(llm=llm, memory= bufferMemory,prompt=prompt_template)` 
`conversation.run(prompt)`

Comment: Welcome to GenAI SE. It's not clear how the rephrasing of the prompt is occurring or how the GPT-3.5 turbo model is being used. Please add more details so others might reproduce a similar behavior to what you are observing.

Comment: I like the spirit of the question, but believe it's hard to nail it down.